# Delete a class Tkinter Button Click

Tags: python, class, tkinter, module

My question is how to delete a class using def func. with a different file

File 1-

```
from Firstpage import*
from creacc import*
def Logclicked():
    del Loginscreen
    Createscreen = Create()


Loginscreen = Firstscreen(Logclicked)
```

File 2-

```
from tkinter import*
from pymongo import *


class Firstscreen:
    def __init__(self,button):
           Createbutton = Button(text="Create A Account?",border=0,highlightthickness=0,width=10,height=2,command=button)
           Createbutton.place(x=30,y=800)
```

This is my code but I am getting a error "Can't access Local variable"
Can someone help me get my code working?

Comment: Post the full error trace.

Comment: Please look at PEP8, it will make your code a lot more readable. Also if you want to destroy a widget, use `.destroy()`. If you want to remove it from the screen, use `.place_forget()`/`.grid_forget()`/`.pack_remove()`.

Comment: Sorry, about my code I am a 14 year old new programmer thats trying to learn new things and become a software engineer in the future. I solved the problem but just wanted to say sorry about my messy code and not providing the whole thing.

Comment: You need to tell Python that `Loginscreen` is a global variable by adding `global Loginscreen` at the beginning of `Logclicked()`.  Note that deleting the class instance does not delete the button instance.